# C# Lists item at location

Tags: c#, list, indexing, at-command

I'm working on C# Lists and i need an item at list location x how do i do it? thanks for helping me

Comment: What is "list location x"? Perhaps it would be clearer if you showed us your code so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> {4,5,6};
var atPos2 = numbers[2];
```

`atPos2` will contain the number 6.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc.aspx) to get the item in that index:

```
var myItem = myList[myIndex];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at the *ElementAt* extension method...

Answer (score 0):

Use or create a (generic)collection that implements [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx)